# Python Exception is not catching the error spawned via 'logging' package when the script is called through a 'subprocess'

Tags: python, exception, logging, subprocess, stderr

I have two different python files (Example: `a.py` & `b.py`). I'm calling `b.py` in `a.py` using subprocess in the following way:

```
try:
    p = sp.Popen(
           ["python", "b.py", "--user_config", json.dumps(user_conf)],
           stdin=sp.PIPE,
           stdout=sp.PIPE,
           stderr=sp.PIPE,
           encoding='cp1252'
        )

    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

else:
    print("Script continues...")
```

**FIRST ISSUE**

`b.py` uses python logging package and it can print out info, warning or error, when it's invoked using `logging.info()`, `logging.warning()` or `logging.error()`.

However, all the `logging.info()`, `logging.warning()` and `logging.error()` is being spawned under `stderr` and not under `stdout` when I'm expecting it to spawn in the following manner:

- stdout - `logging.info()` & `logging.warning()`
- stderr - `logging.error()`

**SECOND ISSUE**

When the error occurs, I want the Exception to catch it but it's not doing it, and the script continues to run.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to handle such issues?

Comment: Well, that’s not how it works. `logging` always logs to stderr, as it’s always secondary output, not primary. It doesn’t matter what logging level it is. And unless the popen call itself somehow fails, there’s no exception to catch. Your script should return a non-zero exit code as an indication that it has failed somehow, you can inspect that from your calling script. Failing that, you’ll need to string-parse the stderr output and decide for yourself whether the script failed or not.

Comment: Thank you @deceze. What if I opt out from using logging and use try..except instead in the `b.py` file? I tried but the exception caught in `b.py` is not being brought forward to be caught by the exception of `a.py`. How to resolve that?

Comment: No exception raised in B will ever be caught by A. You’re invoking a generic program through popen, it could be any command line tool that does not use exceptions internally. The only communication of status between two programs invoked this way is the *exit status*. Additional information can only be communicated via stdout/stderr pipes in some *textual* way which you need to parse again in A.